# How to enable ddr's ecc in Linux?

Tags: linux, powerpc, u-boot

I'm using linux on powerpc p1020,and Freescale provides a whole system include u-boot,linux.The system does not enable ecc check by default.I'm trying to enable this function by modify p1020's ddr_sdram_cfg register,but I failed.In linux,I could only `mmap` register's memory space with PROT_READ permissions and makes linux outage if add PROT_WRITE permissions.Then I try to enable ecc in u-boot,but I failed too,the u-boot stops if I use `mw`  to modify ddr_sdram_cfg.
Could anybody meet this problem?Thanks anyone help me.

Comment: It will depend on the memory controller and actual memory DIMM itself. Most FSL designs also use the MEMC from FSL, which kinda makes is easier to back port code from other machines to your platform. @Joe Kul already mentioned it below, you should not try to enable ECC in the kernel. Do this in u-boot very early. Set ECC settings the same time as u-boot configures MEMC (before u-boot is relocated to RAM). Do it once, do it early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will depend on your target platform, for example you may have [P1020RDB](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=P1020RDB), or something else.

Assuming that SDRAM ECC can be enabled on the platform (this may include extra RAM to hold syndrome bits, e.g. 36-bit data path) then ECC needs to be enabled at the time that SDRAM controller is initialized. It can't be turned on at runtime while the SDRAM is already in use. Thorough study of chip reference manual, target platform documentation, and (ideally) target BSP u-boot source will reveal everything that's needed.